# configuration of highlight.js for non-pre container

Tags: javascript, highlight, highlight.js

I want to use highlight.js in my websie. But it defaults works with `<pre><code></code></pre>` blocks. I like to use just `<code></code>`(actually in `<div><code>`) and use the configuration of [official website](http://highlightjs.org/usage/). But it does not work.

the configuration is as following:

```
hljs.configure({useBR: true});
$('div.code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just dealing with this right now, might as well add it here. My exact issue was highlighting both the block `<pre><code></code></pre>` and the inline `<code></code>`, which is very similar. Note that I used it for the `<code>` tag name the exact code is this.

In place of:

```
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
```

Use (replace 'code' on the first line with your selector)

```
document.querySelectorAll('code').forEach((block) => {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
});
```

However, if there's no `<pre></pre>`, you'll want to use another configuration option, like the `useBr: true` in front of your selector block. You'll have to use `<br>` to signal line breaks then, of course.

```
hljs.configure({useBR: true});

document.querySelectorAll('code').forEach((block) => {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
});
```

One thing to note. If someone's issue is the same as mine (both pre and no-pre), you don't need this option, as the inline code won't contain breaks and the block one is already within the `<pre>`

Comment: Please note useBR is going away in the future and you'll have to jump thru more hoops to use non-standard tags.  With Highlight.js it's very highly recommended that `<pre><code>` be used for mutli-line code snippets.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to this link..i think this can solve it.

http://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#highlightblock-block

highlightBlock(block)

You can use this function to add highlighting to a DOM node containing code

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks for your info...
i will edit my answer... (y)